# How to apply a hyperlink to another slide in the document?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to apply a hyperlink to another slide in the document using VBA?

I have a document that has labelled hyperlinks.
I right-click each one to assign a link which is taking a long time and open to me making mistakes.

Could a loop routine apply the appropriate hyperlinks?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple macro for setting the hyperlink to a slide in the same presentation:

```
Sub SetHyperlinkToSlide()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink
        .Address = ""
        .SubAddress = "257,2,Title"
        .ScreenTip = ""
        .TextToDisplay = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

The 3 numbers in Subaddress are the **SlideID**, the **SlideIndex** and the **SlideTitle** parameters. You don't have to include all three, but you do have to include all the commas. So If you want to jump to a known slide title:

```
.SubAddress = ",,Known Slide Title"
```